# Xcode 6 adds two dots (periods) when coding in Swift for prediction

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode6

Whenever I am typing and want to access functions for a specific object, Xcode adds a second dot after the first one that I have typed. This is frustrating because I have to manually remove one of them every time.

Is there a way to change this?

[image: Here is what I am talking about]

Comment: Bug, not happening with me.

Comment: Probably a random bug with the beta. You might consider filing a bug report with Apple.

Comment: I will do this. Thanks for confirming that it is a bug.

Comment: There seem to be several editor bugs in the beta, but it's good to [report them](http://bugreport.apple.com).

Comment: did you manage to solve this bug? maybe a reinstall?

Comment: Not yet, I do not have the time to reinstall for now

Comment: Got the same, hope a solution be found soon, cause it's a pain in the ass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been fixed in the official release of Xcode 6

Answer (score 1):

If your swift files contain Unicode characters, auto completion will fail even if the characters are comments. So just delete all the Unicode characters, and the auto completion feature will work well !

Comment: I can't think of another IDE that offers automatic unicode detection. Sweet!

Comment: Not happening over here, with lots of Unicode. Maybe it changed over time (beta 4)?

Comment: They fixed it on beta 3

Answer (score 0):

I have found that when I had the following code the bug happened:

`var someString = "0º"`

but when I removed the "º" character

`var someString = "0"`

it didn't put the double dots anymore

Answer (score 0):

Not enough reputation to comment...
Meintus is correct in that I had the double dot issue, and removing non ASCII characters did help.  I'm just here to add the easy way to achieve this. I hadn't typed any non ASCII characters, it turns out it was an example I had copied as a comment for reference.

I found them by clicking on the magnifying glass next to where you type your search.
Select insert pattern, then select "Non-ASCII" Characters

Once I did this and deleted them, the .. Autocomplete stopped :)