# What does it mean when XCode auto-completes Swift properties as "object.?.propertyName"?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a basic understanding of how optional types work in Swift, but I'm confused as to why XCode is auto completing my optional properties when they are defined as

```
class Test {

    var _pageViewController: UIPageViewController? = nil

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        _pageViewController.?.setViewControllers(...)
        // auto completes in xcode to _pageViewController.?.setViewControllers
        ...
```

I'm confused as what the purpose of the '?' property/method on the optional type is for? It doesn't really seem to serve any purpose as far as I can tell?

Comment: I think the two dots are a bug (http://stackoverflow.com/q/24039502/1639670)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two dots are a bug indeed. The purpose of the `?` in Swift in that case is to test AND unwrap your optional variable at the same time. It's the same thing as doing:

```
if let unwrappedPageViewController = _pageViewController {
    unwrappedPageViewController.setViewControllers(...)
}
```

Which means: if the variable `_pageViewController` is not nil, unwrap it and apply the subsequent actions to it.

Hope it helps,